# Struts Autocomplete with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, struts1

I am trying to implement jquery autocomplete on struts framework.
I have implemented exactly similar to [this](http://www.java4s.com/jquery-tutorials/example-get-autocomplete-feature-in-javajsp-with-jquery-api/) link.

http://www.java4s.com/jquery-tutorials/example-get-autocomplete-feature-in-javajsp-with-jquery-api/

But my application is however not calling list.jsp.
Can anyone tell me what could be missing

Please find my below index.jsp

```
<link REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="include/styleee.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="include/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function(){
$('#testcomp1').autocomplete('list.jsp');
});
</script>
<TR>    
        <TD WIDTH="250"><FONT ID="old"><bean:message key="create.testcomp1"/></FONT></TD>
        <TD></TD>
        <TD ALIGN="LEFT">   
          <input type="text"  id="testcomp1" name="testcomp1" size="29" maxlength="100" />
</TR>
<TR>
        <TD WIDTH="250"><FONT ID="old"><"><bean:message key="create.testcomp2"/></FONT></TD>
        <TD></TD>
        <TD ALIGN="LEFT">   
          <html:text styleId="new" property="testcomp2" name="testcomp2" size="29" maxlength="100" value=""/>   
        </TD>
</TR>
```

Please find below list.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<jsp:useBean id="util" class="com.test.Utility" />
    <%
                    String testString = (String)request.getParameter("q");
                    int count = 1;
                    ArrayList dataList = (ArrayList) util.getValidDataList();
                    System.out.println("dataList" + dataList);
                    if (dataList != null && dataList.size()>0)
                    {
                        for (int i=0; i<dataList.size(); i++)
                        {
                            String dataStr = dataList.get(i).toString();
                            String dataStrnew  = dataStr.substring(dataStr.indexOf("^")+1) + "[" + dataStr.substring(0,dataStr.indexOf("^")) + "]";
                            if(cpStrnew.toUpperCase().startsWith(testString.toUpperCase())) 
                            {
                                out.print(dataStr.substring(dataStr.indexOf("^")+1) + "\n");
                                if(count == 10);
                                count++;
                                break;
                            }
                        }                       
                    }
    %>
```

Please let me know where am going wrong and why my list.jsp is not getting called. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show your code otherwise we can't help you solve problem

Comment: Check your browser's console/developer tools for errors. Make sure that the JavaScript files you're including are loading correctly (i.e. the relative paths are correct in relation to the page you're opening). Check your server logs for errors when executing the JSP.